# Better Way to Check for Keys in Python Django Sessions?

Tags: python, django

While this code is working for me, I wonder if there is a better "*Pythonic*" way to check for keys in Django sessions?

```
if 'a' \
and 'b' \
and 'c' \
and 'd' \
and 'e' \
and 'f' \
in request.session:
#do something
```

Basically, I need to make sure all those values exist in my session.

Comment: This is *not* doing what you think. It just checks if 'f' is in the session.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Somehow I had the feeling something was not right about that code and thats why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `all` builtin

```
if all(key in request.session for key in ['a', 'b', ...]):
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

The `all` idiom given in other answers is good, and is probably the best answer on 2.x.

If you're on Python 3.x, as an alternative `session.keys()` will be a [dictview](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) object which supports set operations. So if your set of required keys is static, you can create a `frozenset` of it and then check the set difference against `session.keys()`:

```
required_keys = frozenset(('a','b','c','d','e','f'))

missing_required_keys = required_keys - session.keys()
if missing_keys:
    # at least one key is missing
```

MariusSiuram points out in comments that the `issubset` operation is more efficient than taking set difference, if you don't need the `missing_keys` set:

```
if required_keys <= session.keys():
    # do something
else:
    # at least one key is not in the session
```

I haven't profiled doing this compared to `all` if the list of keys is not static.

Comment: It has guaranteed linear complexity vs. `all` being best-case O(1) and worst case O(n). So I would still prefer `all`, but it's admittedly a bit nitpicky. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/setobject.c#l1240

Comment: I'm still on 2.7 but perhaps one day I will use your solution. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @deets - I tested using 2.6 (all I have on hand) and found that given preconstructed frozen sets and lists, `timeit` shows set difference beating `all` even for the O(1) case of immediate failure. I suspect the overhead for the generator expression outweighs the short-circuiting benefits of `all`. But obviously this a) depends on the actual number of required keys, I used small test ranges that minimize the amount of extra work needed for set difference in that O(1) case and b) doesn't help the OP, since the OP is using 2.7.

Comment: @deets @PetterDeGlopper You can use the `>`, `<` operators to avoid computing `missing_keys` and thus relaxing the "guaranteed linear complexity". It depends on whether having the missing_keys set is relevant or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just another variant of accepted solution:

```
if [key for key in ['a', 'b', ...] if key not in request.session ]:
    ...
```

It works because empty list evaluates to `False` and if it has more than one element it evaluates to `True`.
**EDIT** Former version was buggy.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I may actually use as I was planning on doing `if not all(key in ...` and this will do just that using less code.

Comment: This solution is not a solution, it will generate a list `[False, False, ...]` if no key is in the session, but that still is `True`. On top of this, it suffers from the same problem as the gone answer: the list is possibly costly to build, even though you can short-circuit with `all` on the first occurence of a missing key.

Comment: @deets You were right. The order of statements was wrong. Now it's fixed. As for cost of the list building. Please. We are talking about the keys in a Django session. Do you really expect this dictionary to be that big?

Comment: Yes, the previous version did not work and I went back to @deets solution. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I totally agree that for the given use-case the incurred cost is probably negligible.  But we're teaching a noob a pattern. Why do you insist on not teaching the fundamental concept of generator expressions and early termination if it fits the problem? `if all(...)` is more idiomatic than `if <complex-expression-that-might-evaluate-to-an-empty-collection>` don't you think?

Comment: Agreed. Your answer is the best here indeed.